/dev/mapper/vg_myserver-lv_home: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. (i.e., without -a or -p options) tried everything almost
ve encountered a problem with my logical volume lv_home on a CentOS system. After an attempt to resize this LV from 50GB, it seems something went wrong, and now I'm facing filesystem issues.
Here's what I've encountered and tried so far:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually
Attempted to access the logical volume in single-user mode but couldn't resolve the issue.
Ran df to check the filesystems, and here's the output:
bash
Copy code
Filesystem            1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_myserver-lv_root 51475068   40286004   8567624  83% /
/dev/sda1                487652      35193    426859   8% /boot
tmpfs                   3940748          0   3940748   0% /dev/shm
Tried using e2fsck with an alternate superblock:

csharp
Copy code
[root@myserver ~]# e2fsck -b 32768 -y /dev/mapper/vg_myserver-lv_home
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 43364352 blocks
The physical size of the device is 28311552 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort? yes
Also tried with another superblock backup at 98304, but got the same error regarding the inconsistent filesystem size and physical block size.

Used mke2fs -n to list potential backup superblocks but didn't proceed with further e2fsck commands to avoid worsening the situation.
Given these errors and the failed resizing operation, it seems either the superblock information is corrupt, or the resize operation has led to a mismatch in the recorded size of the filesystem versus its actual size on disk.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can offer tips on resolving this mismatch and recovering the logical volume's filesystem? Thank you.
Msg before:
Hi there, ym lv_home was 50gb someone resizing it didnt work..
i tired everythign in single user mode... to no avail
any tips? i have searched and searched .. thnak you.. .
df
Filesystem            1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_myserver-lv_root
                       51475068   40286004   8567624  83% /
/dev/sda1                487652      35193    426859   8% /boot
tmpfs                   3940748          0   3940748   0% /dev/shm

**


[root@myserver ~]# e2fsck -b alternate_superblock -y /dev/mapper/vg_myserver-lv_home

Invalid non-numeric argument to -b ("alternate_superblock")

[root@myserver ~]# mke2fs -n /dev/mapper/vg_myserver-lv_home
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
7077888 inodes, 28311552 blocks
1415577 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
864 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872

[root@myserver ~]# e2fsck -b 32768 -y /dev/mapper/vg_myserver-lv_home
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 43364352 blocks
The physical size of the device is 28311552 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort? yes

[root@myserver ~]# e2fsck -b 98304 -y /dev/mapper/vg_myserver-lv_home
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 43364352 blocks
The physical size of the device is 28311552 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort? yes
**



It seems you shrink the LV without shrinking the filesystem first. See if you have LVM metadata backups in /etc/lvm/archive created before the resize. You'll need to use it to undo the resize. (Growing the LV back to its original size might work too but only if the LV was a single segment, with LVM you never know for sure). The backup metadata might also be on disk directly, check contents of first 1MiB of the PV.

Perhaps see also https://elatov.github.io/2014/08/revert-lvm-changes/ - please note, doing this is just as dangerous as playing with partition tables. It's possible to lose all data. Moreso if you did more than shrink the LV; if you already reallocated those extents or wrote data to disk, the damage may be permanent.

Unless your CentOS is very old, it defaults to using XFS filesystems, not ext2/3/4. Any advice to use e2fsck and mke2fs -n is applicable to ext2/3/4 filesystem types only.
It looks like you tried to shrink the logical volume from 50 GB to ~28GB, and did not use the --resizefs option of lvreduce. This means it did not modify the filesystem at all before shrinking the LV, causing the tail end of the filesystem to be violently cut off.
Currently there are no production-grade tools for shrinking XFS filesystems non-destructively. XFS filesystem resizing tool is xfs_growfs: as the name indicates, it can only grow a filesystem, not shrink it.
If you have a good backup, re-mkfs the logical volume (e.g. mkfs.xfs /dev/mapper/vg_myserver-lv_home), mount it (now empty) and restore its contents from backup.
If not, use vgcfgrestore and and a copy of the VG configuration stored in /etc/lvm/archive from just before the shrink operation, to undo the shrinking. Then mount the LV, make a backup, shrink it, run mkfs.xfs on the LV, then mount it and restore the backup.

thanks need to fix centos before upgradeing right..
